# Redirecting an inner page to other external domain page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, external

I have an inner page which needs to be redirected to external page, say an events signup page to a survey page created to collect customer experience.

http://www.website.com/careers/events/signup/ to be redirected to Survey page

I have added a 301 redirect in htaccess which wont work. The code I placed is as below.

Redirect 301 /careers/events/signup/ /surveyURL/

The above code does not work, rather loads the page from the folder up without CSS. Please help me to fix it. The website is hosted in apache server and made in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.website.com/careers/events/signup/surveyURL" style="width:100%; height:100%">
<p>failover text in case unable to load</p>
</object>
```

You may need to change the size values to point values rather than percentage. Any good?

Comment: cant we get that work through htaccess. coz i have limitations as to implement it through htaccess only.

Comment: Please see my second answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure mod_rewrite is enabled (httpd.conf) and then add this to your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
#Change below to reflect base eg. /careers/
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^events/signup/surveyURL\.html$ http://www.externalsite.com/externalURL.html [L,R=301,NC]
```